# Category Default Sort Direction When Clicked

Tags: sorting

I'd like Magento to always apply a `descending` sort direction if a user sorts a category by a certain attribute, for instance "price".

**PLEASE NOTE: I am not asking how to choose a default sort attribute for a specific category**. (i.e in this question: [How to list products in descending order?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10305/how-to-list-products-in-descending-order))

I'm asking how - in the event that a user chooses a specific sort option - for Magento to automatically apply `descending` as the sort direction. Native functionality applies an `ascending` sort.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The default order is set here:

```
\Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar::$_direction
```

I think the easiest is to hook into `catalog_block_product_list_collection`, check wether the direction comes from `GET` or from the default and then set it to `desc`. Be careful, I'm sure you have to set it somewhere else (beside the collection) to show it in the frontend.

The alternative might be to set the default direction in the frontend. But I have't checked the template.